# What is the purpose of using element['#object'] in twig templates in drupal 8. How does this work?

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I was finding ways to get data from first level of nested paragraph into second level of paragraph and noticed that `element['#object'].field_name.value` can be used to fetch the field element from the top level.

How does this work? I am trying to find information on this, but I am unable to find it. It will be helpful if someone can give insights on how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just looking a reference to the top level element inside the second level element, like a reference to the parent. It is a circular reference. Hope that is the answer you were looking for.

In PHP code, this is just one way it could be done:

```
<?php
$object = new stdClass();
$object->secondLevel = &$object;
print $object === $object->secondLevel;
```

Also check:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @Beto, this is a great answer, gave me an understanding on how the element is able to get the field_name.value from its parent element.

Comment: Thanks to you @Regokonda. I added a link to an official resource of references in PHP. Good luck!